# Exporting nested data from a MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to export nested fields from MongoDB to a CSV.

From the below code, I would like to extract the scale **name** (e.g. “Security” & “Power”) and the **raw_score** (e.g. 2 & 3, respectively) fields. These four fields would be stored in four columns in a CSV, where each column is an extract field.

```
"results" : {
        "scales" : [
            {
                "scale" : {
                    "name" : "Security",
                    "code" : "SEC",
                    "multiplier" : 1
                },
                "raw_score" : 2
            },
            {
                "scale" : {
                    "name" : "Power",
                    "code" : "POW",
                    "multiplier" : -1
                },
                "raw_score" : 3
            }
        ],
```

In the past I have been successful using dot notation to extract nested fields (a working example below from a previous extraction), yet I am unsure how do to extract fields that share the same name.

```
mongoexport -d production_hoganx_collector_061817 -c records --type=csv -o col_liwc_summary_061817.csv -f user_id,post_analysis.liwc_scores.tone
```

How can I extract the **name** and **raw_score** fields using the mongoexport command? I have tried to export the database to a JSON file and then extract the data via R, however this method takes too long to complete.

If mongoexport is not suitable, I am open to hearing alternatives!

Many thanks,

Comment: I think `$unwind`ing scales would be a good approach. Since it doesnt really make much sense (csv-wise) to have multiple values for the same columns. So by unwiding it you end up with different rows for each of the elements in the scales array. And after that you can use dot notation in your export as you did before.

Comment: @lascort thanks for the advice! I'm very new to Mongo. Could you please give me an example? It would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a one time thing so I suggest using an aggregate to build a new collection with the `scales` array unwinded.

Unwind fans out a document in n documents, where n is the amount of elements in the unwind specified array-type field. So for example if you had a document like this one:

```
{
    name: "Some name",
    email: ["somename@somedomain.com", "name@someotherdomain.com"]
}
```

An unwind on the `email` field would result in two documents:

```
{
    name: "Some name",
    email: "somename@somedomain.com"
},
{
    name: "Some name",
    email: "name@someotherdomain.com"
}
```

So in your case I think you should use that to unwind your scales field like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: yourCondition},
    {$unwind: "$scales"},
    {$project: {
        _id: false,
        scales: true,
        ... other fields ...
    }},
    {$out: "unwindedcollection"}
]);
```

At this point you should be able to use mongoexport from the new collection generated (unwindedcollection), using the dot notation you used before.

Be sure to set false on `_id`, otherwise you'll end up with a duplicate `_id` error. You don't want to project that field so it creates new ids when inserting in the new collection you're dumping your aggregate results.

I'll leave the links to the docs of the concepts I used for this:

aggregate: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

$project: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

$unwind: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

$out: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: This looks fantastic, I really appreciate the detailed example. I apologize but I am few outstanding questions. Can you explain what I would need what I should change the "yourCondition" field to please? Lastly, the "other fields", would that be other fields that I would like to include in the new collection.

Comment: well in yourCondition you can use pretty much any mongo criteria. If you want all documents to be exported you can use `{}`. As for the "other fields" bit, yes, you want to include there all fields that you want to export. Keep in mind though that including `scales` there already includes all nested fields inside it, so you don't need to specify "scales.raw_score" by itself, including scales will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I've run the following in the mongo shell, but when I tried to inspect the unwindedcollection using db.unwindedcollection.findOne(), the shell outputs "null". My code: `db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {}},{$unwind: "$scales"},{$project: {_id: false,scales: true,}},{$out: "unwindedcollection"}])`

Comment: "collection" is not the name of your collection though, from what I see on your mongoexport it should be "records"

Comment: Ah yes a silly mistake. That said, I still get "null" once I correct the code to be pulling from the "records" collection. Am I missing something? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: is that json an actual document of the `results` collection? do they all have that results key in there?

Comment: The collection is called 'records', this collection features many documents, the 'results' document being one of them. Every entry in the 'records' collection contains a 'results' document. I hope that is clear and thanks for your help.